# Getting the cluster size of a hard drive (through code)

Tags: c, winapi, file-io, ntfs

I need to find the cluster size of the users hard drive, through C or C++. The hard drive uses NTFS (though I'd appreciate knowing how it's done on other file systems as well).

I guess what I need is some combination of win32 API calls, but I don't know which.

For instance, typing "fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:" in the windows console gives you "Bytes per cluster", which is what I need. (Though for obvious reasons, I don't want to run that command and parse it's output.)

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't tell you a whole lot. Small files can be stored in the directory node itself.

Comment: FWIW, a file system's cluster size is sometimes also referred to as its "allocation unit" size, e.g.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383356(VS.85).aspx.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [GetDiskFreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364935(VS.85).aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI GetDiskFreeSpace(
  __in   LPCTSTR lpRootPathName,
  __out  LPDWORD lpSectorsPerCluster, // <--
  __out  LPDWORD lpBytesPerSector, // <--
  __out  LPDWORD lpNumberOfFreeClusters,
  __out  LPDWORD lpTotalNumberOfClusters
);
```