# Real size of directory with subdirectories and files on disk

Tags: python

I need to create `img` container for archive some directories and files.

For that I need to create it with `dd`. It's no problem but I can't create it 'cause I don't know real size of the some directories and files. As I understand `img` container don't support dynamic size.

As we can see at image of [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-size-of-folder-using-python/) are two positions `Size` and `Size on disk`.
As I understand I need `Size on disk`, but there is no Python example with `Size on disk`.

If I will use `Size`, maybe I will get an error `Not enough space` when use container.

Of course I can get real `Size on disk` with helping `Block size` of my partition and `Size` and calculate `Size on disk` by hand (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62602765/8497844)) but I think it may be easier.

Q: How do get real `Size on disk` with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limited (partial) solution, it only works for:

- Regular files (not directories, symlinks, or special)
- inode only (file name and metadata not included in size)
- Linux, Unix, or Mac OS (not Windows, sadly)

If the above limits are okay for your needs, then this should work:

```py
import os
import stat

def size_on_disk(path: str):
    '''Get the size on disk for a regular file'''
    st = os.lstat(path)
    if not stat.S_ISREG(st.st_mode):
        raise NotImplementedError('not a regular file')
    st_vfs = os.statvfs(path)
    n_blocks, rem_bytes = divmod(st.st_size, st_vfs.f_frsize)
    return (n_blocks + bool(rem_bytes)) * st_vfs.f_frsize
```

Note that if you're working all in the same volume (disk), then you can do the `os.statvfs()` call once, and reuse the `statvfs` result to greatly speed things up. Here is a version to automatically cache volume info for much higher performance:

```py
import os
import stat

STATVFS_CACHE = {}

def size_on_disk(path: str):
    '''Get the size on disk for a regular file'''
    st = os.lstat(path)
    if not stat.S_ISREG(st.st_mode):
        raise NotImplementedError('not a regular file')
    if not (st_vfs := STATVFS_CACHE.get(st.st_dev)):
        STATVFS_CACHE[st.st_dev] = (st_vfs := os.statvfs(path))
    n_blocks, rem_bytes = divmod(st.st_size, st_vfs.f_frsize)
    return (n_blocks + bool(rem_bytes)) * st_vfs.f_frsize
```

NOTE: Most file systems will also allocate `st_vfs.f_frsize` for an empty file, which this function does not account for. A few file systems are more clever and only allocate a first block to the inode if the file has content, but you can't fully rely on either behavior.

Comment: Do I need to know metadata size of file and dir or it always is equal one block size?

Comment: @Pro It depends a lot on the file system or archive format. In most file systems, the metadata takes up at least 512 bytes (which was a common hard drive block size), but newer file systems typically allow for more, and in some the ammount of metadata stored can be very large. At a minimum, you'll need to account for the file's name (1024 or 4096 bytes are common limits) and whichever permissions are assigned to it (2 bytes min). Security and context metadata adds much more, but isn't used as often.